# How to format postgreSQL queries in a python script for better readability?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, psycopg2, postgresql-9.2

I have another question that is related to a project I am working on for school. I have created a PostgreSQL database, with 5 tables and a bunch of rows. I have created a script that allows a user to search for information in the database using a menu, as well as adding and removing content from one of the tables.

When displaying a table in PostgreSQL CLI itself, it looks pretty clean, however, whenever displaying even a simple table with no user input, it looks really messy. While this is an optional component for the project, I would prefer to have something that looks a little cleaner.

I have tried a variety of potential solutions that I have seen online, even a few from stack overflow, but none of them work. Whenever I try to use any of the methods I have seen and somewhat understand, I always get the error:

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I added a bunch of print statements in my code, to try and figure out why it refuses to typecast. It is being dumb. Knowing me it is probably a simple typo that I can't see. Not even sure if this solution will work, just one of the examples I saw online.

```
try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(database='Blockbuster36', user='dbadmin')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
except psycopg2.DatabaseError:
        print("No connection to database.")
        sys.exit(1)

cursor.execute("select * from Customer;")
tuple = cursor.fetchone()
List_Tuple = list(tuple)

print("Customer_ID | First_Name | Last_Name | Postal_Code | Phone_Num | Member_Date")
print(List_Tuple)
print()
for item in List_Tuple:
        print(item[0]," "*(11-len(str(item[0]))),"|")
        print(item)
        print(type(item))
        print()
        num = str(item[0])
        print(num)
        print(type(num))
        print(str(item[0]))
        print(type(str(item[0])))

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

I uploaded the difference between the output I get through a basic python script and in the PostgreSQL CLI. I have blocked out names in the tables for privacy reasons. https://temporysite.weebly.com/

It doesn't have to look exactly like PostgreSQL, but anything that looks better than the current mess would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples) to do that. You can also set it to pad right or left.
As far as the dates use datetime.strftime.
The following would set the padding to 10 places:

```
print(”{:10}|{:10}".format(item[0], item[1]))
```

Comment: I still get the same error: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You are getting the error because you are using cursor.fetchone() which only returns a single row as a list. You are then trying to iterate thru the first item on the list which is a number. Switch cursor.fetchone() to cursor.fetchall()